# Router-level middlewar: undefined object

Tags: node.js, middleware

This is eligible:

```
someRouter.get('/...',
    (req, res, next) => {
            ...
    },
    (req, res) => {...}
```

while this is NOT eligible:

```
someRouter.get('/...',
            aMiddleware,
            (req, res) => {...}

const aMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {...}
```

the latter gives the error:

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (/Users/Leon/Documents/Projects/NodeJS/DemoJWTinNodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
    at Function.proto.(anonymous function) [as get] (/Users/Leon/Documents/Projects/NodeJS/DemoJWTinNodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:510:19)
    at Object.get (/Users/Leon/Documents/Projects/NodeJS/DemoJWTinNodeJS/src/routes/api/userRoute.js:30:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/Leon/Documents/Projects/NodeJS/DemoJWTinNodeJS/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/Leon/Documents/Projects/NodeJS/DemoJWTinNodeJS/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
```

In my opinion, it basically complains about undefined object, which should have been a middleware.

The middleware function bodies are exactly the same. What's wrong, please?

Comment: Move the `const` definition BEFORE you use it in the `app.get()`.   `const` definitions are not hoisted like `var` is.

Comment: Thanks. @jfriend00. var does not work either. After I putting the function before app.get(), the problem is gone.

Comment: Yeah, the point was to move the `const` definition above it's use, not to switch to `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define the middleware before router if you are using `const` keyword, Or change it to function definition.

**Method 1:**

```
const aMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {...}
someRouter.get('/...',
        aMiddleware,
        (req, res) => {...}
```

**Method 2:**

```
someRouter.get('/...',
        aMiddleware,
        (req, res) => {...}
function aMiddleware(req, res, next){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once I putting the function before app.get(), the problem is gone.

```
const aMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {...}
omeRouter.get('/...',
            aMiddleware,
            (req, res) => {...}
```